# HTMLに埋め込んだMpeg Dashプレイヤーに、音楽/動画ファイル再生URLを適用し再生したい

Tags: javascript, css, html5

現在のソースは下記の通りで、 
画面には、hrefタグに設定した音楽ファイルURLと、MpegDashプレイヤーが埋め込まれています。

そして、音楽ファイルURLを設定したhrefタグ(またはボタンタグ等)をクリックすると、 
MpegDashプレイヤーでその音楽を再生出来るようにしたいのですが、方法が分かりません。 
分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

また、現在は音楽ファイルURLをhrefタグに設定していますが、 
hrefタグでなく、ボタンタグのように押下出来るようなものでしたら何に変えても大丈夫です。

```html
<head>
    <script src="jquery/dash.all.js"></script>
    <script>
        function setupVideo() {
            var url = "http://wams.edgesuite.net/media/MPTExpressionData02/BigBuckBunny_1080p24_IYUV_2ch.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)";
            var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
            var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
            player.startup(); player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoplayer"));
            player.attachSource(url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setupVideo()">
    <div>

     再生したい音楽ファイルURL
        <a id="music" href="http://～省略～Manifest">songA</a>

     埋め込んだMpeg Dashプレイヤー
        <video id="videoplayer" controls></video>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

videosettingのURLにjavascriptで設定します